Как вывести модальное окно на передний план?
Модальное окно отображается за другими элементами на страницe(красного цвета) 
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css";

class Modal extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
}

render() {
    const { active, setActive } = this.props; // Получаем active и setActive из props

    return (
        <div className={modal ${active ? 'active' : ''}}>
            <div className="modal-content">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Modal;

.modal{
z-index: 4;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vh;
background-color: red;
}

Использовала z-index, но не помогло



z-index срабатывает для элементов с позиционированием (свойство position), отличающимся от статичного https://doka.guide/css/z-index/#podskazki  Так же есть и другие особенности... https://habr.com/ru/articles/431046/

На скрине код показан блок с id=menu, код компонента Modal и судя по картинке именно он должен быть поверх остальных. Нужен код css для этого блока
